# Conditional Dependency in Ruby Gemspec

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm building a gem that needs a json gem installed in order for it to work. It doesn't matter which json gem: json_pure, json-jruby, or the C-based json.

Is there a good way of defining this in a gemspec? [This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484482/conditional-gem-dependencies) suggests maintaining a completely separate gem for each version, but it seems like there has got to be a better way.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

Should I just use the [spec.requirements](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#requirements) option to give the user a notice that he/she needs a json gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would suggest a simple text requirement in `spec.requirements`. I would also recommend some sort of load-chaining when the gem first loads:

```
# in init.rb and/or rails/init.rb:
unless Object.const_defined?(:JSON)
  begin
    require 'json_pure'
  rescue LoadError
    begin
      require 'json-ruby'
    rescue LoadError
      require 'json'
    end
  end
end
unless Object.const_defined?(:JSON)
  raise "Could not load gem MyGem; did you install one of json_pur, json-ruby, or the C-based json library?"
end
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. The cool thing with all of the JSON gems is that you just require 'json' so it will simplify the load-chaining.