# How to make my gem depend on either json_pure or json?

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

Since the json_pure and json gems are compatible, is there a way to create another gem that depends on either one?

If not, would a gem post-install be a good place to check for one of the json gems and warn if neither is installed?

Any other solutions?

UPDATE - response to @tadman with clarifications

If it were possible to "force" either one or the other, then it wouldn't be a bad thing to force, correct? Your question about "forcing" is a rhetorical one, implying that the answer to my question is "no".

Also, I'm under the impression that people usually don't look through each of dependencies and ask, "Do I need this one?"

Regarding an error message about the missing dependency - in my mind, it is not an acceptable user experience to tell the user about a missing dep only at the point when they're trying to run their app. They need to know earlier, which I why I mentioned the post-install message.

Comment: Looks like my question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835927/conditional-dependency-in-ruby-gemspec

Answer (score 0):

Why would you force this dependency? Just list it as a requirement and let the user choose which they prefer.

The `Gemfile` specification must list those gems which you want, and does not support picking between several options. The `.gemspec` file follows the same sort of structure.

To be a good citizen, your gem should rescue from a failure to load one of these by presenting a clean, concise message that describes the problem and the remedy. This would avoid an ugly and confusing stack-trace.