# Writing a Jeweler Rakefile that adds dependencies depending on RUBY_ENGINE (ruby or jruby)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I have a Rakefile that includes this:

```
Jeweler::Tasks.new do |gem|
  # ...
  gem.add_dependency('json')
end
```

The gemspec that this generates builds a gem that can't be installed on jruby because the 'json' gem is native.

For jruby, this would have to be:

```
Jeweler::Tasks.new do |gem|
  # ...
  gem.add_dependency('json-jruby')
end
```

How do I conditionally add the dependency for 'json-jruby' when RUBY_ENGINE == 'java'?

It seems like my only option is to manually edit the gemspec file that jeweler generates to add the RUBY_ENGINE check. But I'd rather avoid this, since it kind of defeats the purpose of using jeweler in the first place.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484482/conditional-gem-dependencies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620342/how-do-i-add-conditional-rubygem-requirements-to-a-gem-specification

Comment: Unfortunately none of those questions deal with the problem here, which I guess is specific to Jeweler. I'm getting the feeling that the answer here is that this is simply not doable with the current version of Jeweler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging around, I've come to the conclusion that the problem here isn't so much the limitation in Jeweler as it is a problem with how the `json-jruby` gem is named.

In a perfect world, the `json-jruby` gem should be named just `json`. That way when the gem file is built under JRuby (i.e. `jgem build json-jruby.gem`), the resulting gem file would be named `json-1.4.3-universal-java-1.6.gem` (RubyGems names the file based on the 'platform' property in the gemspec). When installed with the appropriate platform in the gem name, everything works transparently. There's no need to explicitly require `json-jruby`. RubyGems uses the appropriate version automatically.

I've contacted the maintainer of the `json` gem to see if he'd be willing to get json-1.4.3-universal-java-1.6.gem added to his gemcutter repo, but in the meantime you can download the drop-in jruby json gem here: http://roughest.net/json-1.4.3-universal-java-1.6.gem